# 2 humidistats for 1 humidifier

Tags: thermostat, nest, humidifier, relay

I have two zones in my house with a damper system and want to move away from using my humidistat to control the solonoid valve on my humidifier and instead use my Nest thermostats.

My zone control panel has a spot for a humidifier control, but I'm not certain how it works so I never hooked it up. My only thought is that the W heat wire triggers it to turn on. Since the Nests measure humidity, they'll be more accurate anyway.

If I had only one Nest thermostat, a simple 24V relay would suffice, but I have 2. **I want it so if either thermostat turns on the humidifier, then the humidifier turns on.**

I don't know enough about electrical engineering to figure out a good solution to this problem.

Another idea is to buy another zone control panel and only hook up certain wires to fake it.

Comment: What make and model is your existing zone control board?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel My zone control board is the Aprilaire 6404

Comment: So *two* 24V relays, each one thrown by a Nest.

Comment: BTW: I'm not seeing anything in the [Aprilaire 6404's manual](https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/rp/hnxkawhame/aprilaire-6404-6403-zoned-comfort-control-installation-guide-b2206566b.pdf?u=o29tdq) about it being able to control a humidifier

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica How would I do it with two relays? Could you post a solution with an image showing how I'd wire something like that?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Depends on the manual. Some say HUM is for Humidifier. I think the unit itself says that too.

Comment: Can you post photos of your existing zone board, actually?